# Neither a Tripod or monopod

Tags: tripod, monopod

I am looking for neither a tripod nor monopod. I actually think the term is "Telescopic rod" which is used for only digital cameras which is almost like a monopod except it cannot be extended (just handheld). lets Just say it is a stabilizer. I am referring this term to a hama star mini digital camera multipod purpose.

Now I just want that "Telescopic rod" for my DSLR.

Do any of you idea what is the exact term for my description ?

sorry guys I really have no better idea of expressing what it can be.

Looking forward to your comments and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about something similar to [this](http://www.adorama.com/DOG100.html?gclid=CM3P7pHpt7kCFQyk4AodPUIAeA).  Basically a little stick that can attach to the mount that you can hold on to as an extra grip surface?  Those fall under the category of rigs, which are support structures that are designed to be used against the body and not the ground.  There are a wide variety of types available ranging from the basic stick type to shoulder mounts and the like.  [This](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-SLR-Video-Stabilizers/ci/3926/N/4075788764) is B&H's selection of stabilizers and rigs for DSLR.

Comment: Bracket, Brace, Support, etc. You covered every imaginable thing I could think of. Impressive gear on these links. Nice.

Comment: @AJ Henderson Close enough but do you have any other alternates too just curious to know. But I don't know where to get it in Europe. Shipping from the US is very expensive :(

Comment: @DRK - I do not know of any distributors in Europe as I live in New York state which is only about 3 hours away from the city where B&H is located.  I'm sure that there would be European distributors available though.  I'd try finding an item you like from B&H and then search for the specific item.  Most of the major rig manufacturers have international distribution.

Comment: The first link is to a pistol grip head which is a special kind of ball head and is meant to be used in conjuction with a tripod or monopod.

Comment: @AJHenderson I see. I will try to look it up and will post it here !!

Comment: @AJHenderson I would expect this http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/900253-REG/Dot_Line_dl_0920_Stabilizer_Grip.html

Comment: @MichaelClark - yeah, I know it wasn't perfect, but it is still fairly similar.  I was really looking from something like what DRK linked (which I had seen before, but couldn't find when looking).  It is designed to be able to go on a tripod or monopod, but it appeared it could go without them as well.